# windows phone "Error 24 Type X' already defines a member called 'X' with the same parameter type"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have got the error :
Error   24 Type 'X.volSays' already defines a member called 'volSays' with the same parameter types

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace X
{
    public partial class volSays : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public volSays()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this error ?

Comment: It's a partial class, you may have made an accidental copy. That would give this error. Carefuly scrutinize your solution explorer, and/or use Ctrl+F to find the copy.